# How to avoid aligning text with previous selection sections in html css?

Tags: html, css, alignment, margin

I have an index.html file and a style file. Here is how this section looks in my webpage looks so far.

[image: Webpage]

Notice how quiz is indented. However, I used the same style for Quiz and User Information. In my style file:

```
.header{
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  color: #0381a5;
  font-family: georgia;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0381a5;
  width: 95%;
}

.sub-header{
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  color: #0381a5;
  font-family: georgia;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0381a5;
  width: 92.5%;
}
```

They are both sub-headers. Here is how I called the style in index.html

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cognition Study</title>
</head>

<form action="/cgi-bin/form.py">
  <div class="header">
    Cognition Study
  </div>
  <!--paragraph-->
  <div class="sub-header">
    User Information
  </div>
  <!--dropdown menus-->
  <div class="txt">Continue to the quiz section below.</div>
  <br>
  <div class="sub-header">
    Quiz
  </div>
```

What is causing "Quiz" to be indented, and how can I make it aligned with "User Information"?

Comment: We can't help based off screenshots of your code, especially because the problem isn't in the code you're showing us. Please create a snippet here with all of the page's relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: Is your website online? It's really hard to debug CSS without being able to play with it in a debugger. Alternatively you could post a PLUNKER with similar code and try to recreate it there.

Comment: the code provided does not replicate the issue as per the image in the question...

Comment: This is all the relevant code...I don't know what else could be affecting this

Answer (score 0):

I used your code and don't see any problems. Perhaps the problem with your browser?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFDOf.png)

```css
.header{
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  margin-left: 2.5%;
  color: #0381a5;
  font-family: georgia;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0381a5;
  width: 95%;
}

.sub-header{
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  color: #0381a5;
  font-family: georgia;
  font-size: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0381a5;
  width: 92.5%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cognition Study</title>
</head>

<form action="/cgi-bin/form.py">
  <div class="header">
    Cognition Study
  </div>
  <!--paragraph-->
  <div class="sub-header">
    User Information
  </div>
  <!--dropdown menus-->
  <div class="txt">Continue to the quiz section below.</div>
  <br>
  <div class="sub-header">
    Quiz
  </div>
```